# Overwriting form elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, function, return-value

My application is used to calculate the household budget. I encountered the following problem.

At first, I entered a few items into the list
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkoiI.png)

I clicked the edit button to change the first item
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxqa2.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyO5o.png)

after saving the changes i did exactly the same for the second item
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb2BR.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGnYd.png)

At the end you can see how both items from the list changed their name and value.
I wonder what the problem could be because each element when added also receives a unique ID that does not change. Please help :D
I tried to check if it is changed when clicking the Save button, but it works fine anyway. I don't know what else I can check

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("edit-form").addEventListener("submit", 
(event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      incomes[index].name = name.value;
      incomes[index].amount = amount.value;
      item.textContent = `${name.value}: ${amount.value} PLN`;
      item.appendChild(btns);
      updateTotalIncomes();
      updateFinalScore();
      modal.style.display = "none";
      return;
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to find row index when submitting a form.
Then you can change values using a row index

Example:

```
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
function submit(formValues) {
  setTableData((prev)=> {
    const rowIndex = prev.findIndex((item)=> item.uniqueId === formValues.uniqueId);
    prev[rowIndex] = formValues;
    return [...prev];
  });
}
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand what exactly you mean :(

Comment: You are using ReactJS right?. I mean, when you done editing and when you hit save button. You need to identify which row is edited and gonna replace a edited row with new data right?
To do that. First we need to find index of row that we are editing. Once we got a index of a row we can use this to replace the row data.

Can you provide me with your code to better answer?

Comment: I solved this problem. I forgot about remove the listiner in form but thanks for help :D